# Does using more variables make the code more inefficient?

Tags: php, performance

Does using more variables have any impact on the efficiency of the code?
I.E. does this code:

```
function get_random_string($valid_chars, $length)
{
    $random_string = "";
    $num_valid_chars = strlen($valid_chars);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++)
    {
        $random_pick = mt_rand(1, $num_valid_chars);
        $random_char = $valid_chars[$random_pick-1];
        $random_string .= $random_char;
    }
    return $random_string;
}
```

work more efficiently than this:

```
function get_random_string($valid_chars, $length)
{
    $random_string = "";
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++)
    $num_valid_chars=strlen($valid_chars);
    {
        $random_string .= $valid_chars[mt_rand(1, $num_valid_chars)-1];
    }
    return $random_string;
}
```

Comment: It's not whether it makes a difference, it's whether it makes enough of a difference to override other considerations (like readability, code size, and coding style rules).

Comment: The upper function does some things more efficiently than the lower one (for example, not calling `strlen` once per loop) and some things less efficiently (for example, the wasted intermediate storage to `random_char`).

Comment: @delnan I know readability and code size are affected by the number of variables used, but that's not the topic.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz That's assuming the variables have a cost opposed to temporaries (really, that's not a given) and that the `strlen` call has a cost (while a PHP interpreter likely won't recognize it's loop invariant and move it out, it probably returns a field of a C struct, which is extremely cheap).

Comment: @GiulioMuscarello I assume that one who understands that and its implications wouldn't ask *if there is a difference*, but rather how the difference can be determined and perhaps whether it's generally great enough to matter.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Thanks for the note, I edited the code so that both do the same number of calls to the same functions.

Comment: @delnan: You would think so, but as it happens, PHP's `strlen` function is [surprisingly expensive](http://formvista.com/fv-b-12-164/php-performance-tip---reducing-use-of-strlen--.html) even though it "just" looks up the stored length rather than having to count characters. (The guess on that page about why it's slow is wrong, but it is in fact that slow.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end, you won't notice the difference unless your real code completly different from the example.

Remember that even if PHP is not being compiled per se, the code still gets parsed and op-code compiled and even cached. The result can be dramaticaly different from what you coded in the first place.

Your job as a developper is to make clean, readable code that answer's the client request. Obviously, don't use techniques that forcefuly makes the code bloaty and slow, the rest is the Zend Optimizer's job, don't worry about it.